# the space of noncrossing partitions of S^1

Tags: co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology

A non-crossing partition of the set $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}=\{ 1, 2,\dots,m n\}=\bigcup X_i$ is a disjoint union of sets such that

- if $ a < b \in X_1$ and $ c < d \in X_2$  then we can't have $a < c < b < d$.

If additionally I require that $x \mapsto mx$ takes $X_i \to \{0, m, 2m, \dots, (n-1)m\}$ is there a name for this kind of partition?

---

I'd like to know more about the limit as $n \mapsto \infty$ which I've been calling "congruent non-crossing partitions of $S^1$"

- n-tuples $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ of disjoint unions of $ S^1$
- $X_1 \cup \dots \cup X_n = S^1$ and $X_i \cap X_j = \varnothing$
- the map $x \mapsto nx (\mod 1)$ takes $X_i \to S^1$

Is there a name for this space?  Does it now have nice cell decomposition?

Comment: What topology are you putting on it?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your construction, then for each $n\geq2$, your 'space' of partitions is precisely two copies of $S^1$. Each $X_i$ looks like a half-open interval $[a_i,a_{i+1})$ or $(a_i,a_{i+1}]$ that covers precisely $1/n$ of $S^1$, so the whole partition is determined by $a_1$ and the choice of whether to use the first or second sort of half-open interval. As you haven't explained what topology you want to use, I don't know how you want to piece this together as $n\to\infty$. But, thinking of this as a collection of coverings of the circle, perhaps the limiting object is a solenoid?

Answer (score 2):

Am I right that you consider $x \mapsto mx$ modulo $mn$? This property is then equivalent to simply consider noncrossing partitions of $\{1,\ldots,mn\}$ where each block has size $n$.

Given any multiset of block sizes, Kreweras counted the number of noncrossing set partitions with these block sizes, see [[Arm](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611106), Theorem 4.4.2].

Drew Armstrong studied then a variant of this in Section 3.3 thereof where he studied $n$-divisible noncrossing partitions where each block size is divisible by $n$.

In an upcoming paper, Christian Krattenthaler (see an abstract [here](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpage.math.tu-berlin.de%2F~felsner%2FKolKom06%2Fabstracts.ps&ei=d987UvWIB6HM0QWYs4CgCg&usg=AFQjCNFtcILEswjJVUJOOhEMaRKQcem4ug&bvm=bv.52434380,d.d2k&cad=rja)) promised to study as well noncrossing partitions with completely fixed block sizes which are moreover rotationally invariant under $r^k$ for some $k$ where $r$ is the primitive rotation given by $x \mapsto x+1 (\text{mod }mn)$.

I have never heart of any limit construction for $n \rightarrow \infty$, but others might...